# Clean way to replace all "&#.." characters to normal ones in URL

Tags: javascript

Couldn't find any solution around, so: I have an URL with crappy cgaracters like:

```
var wwwlink = 'http:&#x2F;&#x2F;www.nytimes.com&#x2F;2014&#x2F;03&#x2F;10&#x2F;business&#x2F;staking-1-billion-that-herbalife-will-fail-then-ackman-lobbying-to-bring-it-down.html?hp&amp;_r=0';
```

Is there a clean solution to decode all possible **&#..** thigs to normal characters? The only possible solution I have found is **.replace** one, having several .replace calls for any possible character. Of course the solution is plausable because urls, in most cases, have like 5 different characters to replace, but may be there's a better one?

**edit:** the solution must be runnable under node.js.

Comment: `decodeURIComponent(url.replace(/\+/g, ' '));`

Comment: @Vallentin - Did you test that?

Comment: @techfoobar I seem to have missed the point that he wanted to replace certain things, I read it as a pure URL Decoding problem.

Comment: @Vallentin - Me too, actually! And was testing out pretty much the same thing in the console and found out that it won't work!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try with:

```
var div = document.createElement('div');
    div.innerHTML = wwwlink;

var output = div.firstChild.nodeValue;
```

Output:

```
http://www.nytimes.com/2014/03/10/business/staking-1-billion-that-herbalife-will-fail-then-ackman-lobbying-to-bring-it-down.html?hp&_r=0
```

For node.js you can give a shoot with:

```
var Entities = require('html-entities').XmlEntities;
entities = new Entities();
console.log(entities.decode(wwwlink));
```

Comment: yeah, but the only problem is that I am executing a code under node.js.. probably I should update the question to reflect that.